# wsl ubuntu .bashrc stopped running

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using WSL for a while now but one of the recent-ish Windows updates has seemingly caused it to stop running my .bashrc file wherein I set up a few handy aliases and other things. Seemingly I've also lost the console formatting.

Any suggestions of where to start? I'm not averse to just blitzing it and reinstalling (bonus question: what's the best way to do this?) but I'd prefer to try and better my Linux knowledge and understand what went wrong if possible.

Comment: Playing with `wslconfig /list` I learned at one point during the transition to newer builds I had multiple installs of ubuntu, the original was called `Legacy (default)` which was the one without the bashrc executing. Ultimatley, I unregistered this (using `wslconfig /unregister Default`) so can't run the permissions change suggested unfortunately.

For anyone finding this in the future `wslconfig` is worth knowing about full details currently here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

Comment: yes, I had multiple but because I was using `bash.exe` (as opposed to `ubuntu`) to launch, it was loading the Legacy version, removing that and setting ubuntu to the default and now running ubuntu and bashrc is firing as expected.